# Is there a compatible way to write href?

Tags: html, anchor, href

For example, in file `test.php`:

```
<a href="someting/?start=1">go</a>;
```

so that no matter where this `test.php` is, whether in `Document_Root/Test/` directory or in `Document_Root/Production/` directory, the anchor will point to itself.

Answer (score 10):

To write a link that will only change the query string, just use

```
<a href="?foo=bar">whatever</a>
```

So if you're at `http://the/current/url.php`, it goes to `http://the/current/url.php?foo=bar`, or if you're `http://somewhere/else?entire=ly`, it goes to `http://somewhere/else?foo=bar`.

Comment: If it is, accept his answer by clicking on the check to the left