# Only URL-Parameter as href arguments in anchor

Tags: html, anchor, href

I want to create an anchor which navigates to the same page, but changes some Url paramters. Here is an example:

```
<a href='?hello=world'>Test</a>
```

I tested it in IE, Chrome and Firefox but want to avaid any nasty suprises. So is this a valid href argument for an anchor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/873743/453277

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you right, but isn't an anchor starting with the `#`? Like in `<a href='#header1'>Test</a>`. From this link you will jump to `<span id="header1">Header 1</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` And the sourche http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html